# Test launch failed due to internal error: Running tests on UI thread

Tags: android, unit-testing, robotium

I am creating a unit testing project for my application. It was working fine before. but I had updated the **ADT plugin** and **android SDK**. after that I could launch this project but cannot separately run the **test cases**. It will execute first test case and then stop. Before I could manually execute the second testcase.  But now when I tried to do that I got error "Test launch failed due to internal error: Running tests on UI thread".please help me to solve this...
note:using robotium 3.2.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you running the indidual method from a test from the Eclipse Junit window?  Try running the test method from project explorer.  Right click and run from the Project Explorer, not the JUnit window.

[image: Run as Android JUnit Test form Project Explorer only]

Answer (score 1):

RightHandedMonkey's work-around works for me.

It also looks like this is a known issue and will be fixed in ADT 21 (see: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34170)

There's also a changelist there to pull the fix if you are building the ADT from source.